# Simple web app to display location between two phones

Tags: javascript, web-applications, geolocation

I'm trying to create a simple, one-page web app that just displays the location between two phones. The two phones will be fixed (basically my phone and a friend's phone, both iPhones), ie not something the user can configure. Is this possible with just html/css/javascript? If so, I'd love to get some pointers on where to get started. Should I use the geolocation API? How would I identify which two phones I'm trying to calculate the distance?